# Subscribe to Topics using AWS-IOT with .NET

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-iot, aws-sdk-net

I have spent many hours looking for a way to subscribe to a topic using the AWSSDK.IoT library.  I can publish easily enough, but can't figure out the subscription part.

I am using the AmazonIotDataClient (AWSSDK.IotData), but have also tried the AmazonIotClient (AWSSDK.Iot).  I am not having any luck with either.  Just doesn't seem to be in the .NET SDK?

Code to publish:

```
public void SendMessage(string topic, PropertyCollection collection)
{    
     var json = collection.ToJson();
     using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
     {
         var request = new PublishRequest
         {
             Topic = topic,
             Payload = stream
         };
         _client.Publish(request);
     }
}
```

Comment: From what I can tell, there is no way to do this with Amazons own .NET SDK.  Seems like a massive oversight, but using a third party client like mqttnet or m2mqtt does allow me to both publish and subscribe quite easily.